# Using ArcGIS Calculate Field with condition?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, if-statement

I have a point feature class which has two fields for two different sets of geographic coordinates (called "GPS_LON", "GPS_LAT" and "SHIFT_LON", "SHIFT_LAT"). I want to calculate the approximate metric distance between the two sets (assuming that 1 deg lat is ~111000 m).
If I use the VB expression is all right. If I use the Python one, I get a syntax error at the first line:

```
degdist = math.sqrt( (( !SHIFT_LON! - !GPS_LON! )**2) + ( (!SHIFT_LAT! - !GPS_LAT! )**2))
mdist = degdist * 111000
```

The point of using Python is, that I need to set a condition: not all of my "GPS_LON", "GPS_LAT" were measured, thus I have zeros, and for those points with zeros I do not want to calculate the distance but rather have  values.

That was my attempt, which also returns syntax errors(!):

```
if !GPS_LON! == 0:
    mdist = None
else:
   degdist = math.sqrt( (( !SHIFT_LON! - !GPS_LON! )**2) + ( (!SHIFT_LAT! - !GPS_LAT! )**2))
   mdist = degdist * 111000
end if
```

[image]

I am still a Python novice.

Comment: Look closely at [this example](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0). For example you need to define the function name, and not enlose the field names with !! inside the function.

Comment: Keep in mind that your Python function in the Pre-Logic Script Code block needs to be valid Python.  The code which *calls* that function is where you pack in the magic characters.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have changed the code as following:

def distance(MagDist):
    if GPS_LON == 0:
        MagDist = None
    else:
       degdist = math.sqrt ( SHIFT_LON - GPS_LON )**2) + ( SHIFT_LAT - GPS_LAT )**2))
       MagDist = degdist * 111000

but I still get a syntax error at line 5.

Comment: No, that's still not correct. If you want to use multiple fields, you need to pass them into the function. Please be sure to [Edit] the question with any clarifications. Comments are illegible for that purpose (and therefore discouraged)

Comment: Be careful with indentation in Python. And Python has no `end if` clause. You have to remove it.

Comment: I'm there again. I have tried the code (in a model) with another dataset, which has exactly the same format as the first one. I have now modified the first part of the if-statement as follows: if gps_lon == 0: return(-1) else: deg_dist = math.sqrt((( SHIFT_LON - GPS_LON )**2) + (( SHIFT_LAT - GPS_LAT )**2)) return (deg_dist * 111000) Unfortunately, however, this part of the condition does not work and the calculator runs as if there is no 0 values. I have also tried to modify it to if gps_lon != 0: deg_dist = math.sqrt((( SHIFT_LON - GPS_LON )**2) + (( SHIFT_LAT - GPS_LAT )**2)) return (deg_di

Comment: If these explanations are about your question, please add those to your question by clicking **Edit** text under the question, instead of adding as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to satisfy the syntax for Field Calculator, you need to define the function and input variables in the "Pre-Logic Script Code". The output field should be left out unless values in that field are part of the function. Therefore, your pre-logic script should be

`def calc(gps_lon, gps_lat, shift_lon, shift_lat):
    if gps_lon == 0:
        return None
    else:
        deg_dist = math.sqrt( ((shift_lon - gps_lon)**2) + ((shift_lat - gps_lat)**2) )
        return (degdist * 111000)`

where your input variables are defined in the function, and your expression should be

`calc(!GPS_LON!, !GPS_LAT!, !SHIFT_LON!, !SHIFT_LAT!)`

where each of the fields that corresponds with an input variable is listed in the same variable position within the function. My use of `calc` as the function name is just habit, and it could be set to anything you want.

In general, the help documentation pages from ESRI provide a lot of the useful information for writing these scripts (as linked in the comments on OP). [Esri Documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0)

Comment: Thanks, now I see where I was wrong. However I still get an error at this step when executing my model (ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Calculate MagDist)).

Comment: is this tool part of a larger model? The dreaded 999999 Error doesn't provide us with much information, but the fact that its not a specific error relative to the field calculator leads me to believe its originating elsewhere.